# SPUtility not working correctly

Tags: sputility

I just started using this tool, so I tested `SetValue` in order to familiarize myself with it. It seemed to only work whenever I hit the "Ok" button to the Content Editor web part of the new/edit form. Whenever I actually tried to create/edit a form, I was met with blank fields. Could someone let me know what I could be missing?

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/MySite/SiteAssets/Code/SPUtility/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // wait for the window to load
    $(document).ready(function () {
       // EXAMPLE: Set the value of the Title field to Hello world!
       SPUtility.GetSPField('Title').SetValue('Hello world!');
       SPUtility.GetSPField('Occurrence No.').SetValue('25');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I once ran into a problem where my script was not executing because I forgot the "type" attribute in the script tag.  Try changing your opening script tag to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @DylanCristy You are the man! That worked! Thanks! You should post that as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: I will add it as a real answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once ran into a problem where my script was not executing because I forgot the "type" attribute in the script tag. Try changing your opening script tag to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```